# How to fetch videos from server in flutter?

Tags: api, dart, flutter

I'm trying to fetch videos from the internet and show them into listview in flutter.

Comment: Pls show what is already done and what is the fine-grained problem that you can't actually solve?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter packages has a video_player plugin which does just that .
Try out it's sample app .

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player